# Typescript in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web 6.0 not compiling in DevOps Pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-pipelines

We changed our visual studio c# web project type from old .net-framework-4.8 asp.net to .net-6.0 microsoft.net.sdk.web.

However, all works fine in Visual Studio, serverside c# code and clientside typescript code is compiled/transpiled correctly.

But when we let compile the solution through DevOps pipe, the typescript is neither compiled nor transpiled to JS-files.

This worked before with the old project type.

The DevOps pipe has "Visual Studio Build" task for compiling the solution:

[image]

What do we need to do, the new project type's type scripts are compiling and transpiling as well as the old one did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. Add the package "**`Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`**" to your project.

   - Open your solution in Visual Studio.
   - In Solution Explorer, right-click on the solution node and select "**Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**".
   - In the **Browse** tab, search for and install the package "**`Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`**".
2. Add below '**`<Import>`**' node to the project file (**`.csproj`**).

   ```xml
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
     . . .
     <ImportGroup>
       <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
     </ImportGroup>
   </Project>
   ```

Comment: That worked, I just added the Nuget, checked-in et vóilà! Strange that this is somehow required in pipeline but not required in Visual Studio ... The Second Step with <import> I skipped, seems this is not nessecary (at least in my case). Thanks!